# How do I properly configure KVM

Tags: ip, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, linux-networking, mac-address

I have a remote dedicated server on which I have installed KVM.

When trying to create my first virtual machine I am unable to ssh to the machine.

I assumed that I needed another ip address so I obtained one from the people at the data centre but it is still the same result. Unable to ssh.

It seems that the mac address generated by the data centere does not correspond to my machine.

So, my two questions are as follows:

1. Is it possible to configure publicly accessible virtual machines without assiging extra ip addresses, or for clarity to just use the ip address and mac address of the host machine?
2. In the event that this is not possible what specific information should I be asking for in regards to my second ip address and it's mac addres so I can make this work?

Comment: Who is the service provider? Exactly what instructions did they give you?

Comment: Service provider is one provider, but they didn't actually give me any instructions yet. I have been dealing with softalicious tech support and they claim I need another MAC address.

Comment: "One provider"? I never heard of them?

Comment: Even without the data centre information how would I configure this?

Comment: Even without the required information, how would we be able to help you? Seriously now, all the telepaths are on vacation. Always.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Redhat or CentOS, then the network interface won't have an IP by default. You need to configure the interface from within the VM.

If you enabled vnc for the VM while installation:

To do so, reach the host (make sure X11 forwarding is enabled, i.e., 'ssh -X') and execute:

```
    virsh list --all
    virt-viewer <vm_number>
```

where vm_number is the number shown in the first column corresponding to the VM in the first command.

Once you are in the VM, configure the network interface inside the VM with your choice. Refer to [CentOS 6.5 not bringing up network interface automatically after reboot [ifup eth0]](https://serverfault.com/questions/589990/centos-6-5-not-bringing-up-network-interface-automatically-after-reboot-ifup-et).

If it is a static public IP, you will need to configure the bridge to allow that as in [Centos/OVH: public IP on KVM virtual machine](https://serverfault.com/questions/436529/centos-ovh-public-ip-on-kvm-virtual-machine).

Comment: Ahmed, welcome to SF!  May I say that I've been impressed by the clarity and quality of the first couple of answers I've seen from you?  I've learned something from one of them, which always cheers me up.  Thank you; I hope you stay around and keep writing like this for some time to come.

Comment: Thanks MadHatter. I will do my best to stay on SF and share knowledge.